# UIButtons dont behave as expected

Tags: swift, uibutton

Im using Auto Layout and cant figure out why on the simulator the buttons show up differently. Pictures of  IB and simulator:

[image]

[image]

I let AutoLayout set the constraints for me. The buttons have fix distances  set to eachother but on the simulator this isnt the case. The bounds seem to be also off. This is the code i use to set the buttons:

```
class Colors {
let colorTop = UIColor(red: 192.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 42.0/255.0, alpha: 0.05).CGColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 35.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 0.05).CGColor

let gl: CAGradientLayer

init() {
    gl = CAGradientLayer()
    gl.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gl.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
}
func niceButton(button : UIButton, sz : CGFloat)
{
    let color = Colors()

    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    button.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: sz)
    color.gl.frame = button.bounds
    color.gl.cornerRadius = 10.0
    //color.gl.borderWidth = 1.0
    button.layer.insertSublayer(color.gl, atIndex: 0)
}
```

}
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is interface builder giving you any warnings about ambiguous constraints?

Comment: Can you post a repository for the project?